# YEAR() and beberlei/DoctrineExtensions

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, doctrine-extensions

I have to make requests with YEAR and I installed beberlei/DoctrineExtensions with doctrine command. I added the requested annotations

```
doctrine:
   orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
        dql:
            datetime_functions:
                year: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Year
```

, but it does not work, I have this error:

> Attempted to load class "Year" from namespace
>   "DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql". Did you forget a "use" statement for
>   another namespace?

The request:

```
public function groupTypeInterArray(){
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('i')
            ->select('YEAR(i.interventionDate)');
    return $qb->getQuery()->execute();
}
```

Config Doctrine

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: pdo_mysql
        host: '%database_host%'
        port: '%database_port%'
        dbname: '%database_name%'
        user: '%database_user%'
        password: '%database_password%'
        charset: UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/data/data.sqlite'
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #path: '%database_path%'

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
        dql:
            datetime_functions:
                Year: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Year
```

I searched all the afternoon, but I didn't find the solution.

Thank you in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04LUL.jpg)

Comment: Have you install ```beberlei/DoctrineExtensions``` using ```composer require beberlei/DoctrineExtensions``` command

Comment: Yes, I did it but it doesn't work

Comment: Can you please check with change "datetime_functions" with "string_functions"

Comment: I have the same error with "string_functions".

Comment: Can you please add paste your query?

Comment: Of course, I just edited my message to put it.

Comment: Query seems to okay, Which symfony version are you using?

Comment: I use Symfony 3.4.

Comment: Can you please share your configuration of doctrine from config.yml?

Comment: Yes, it's good,  I  edited my message to put it.

Comment: Strange, because I have replaced your configuration in my local project and still it's working fine, if you are using linux can you please fire command in terminal: ```la -la vendor/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions/src/Query/Mysql/Year.php``` in your project directory and paste the output over here?

Comment: I don't use linux sorry.

Comment: Okay then can you please check the above file is available in your vendor or not?

Comment: And also please check permission of that file if available.

Comment: vendor/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions/src/Query/Mysql/Year.php it's ok. And the permission? where should I look?

Comment: Which os you are using? Windows ?

Comment: Yes, It's Windows 10.

Comment: okay then open your cmd and then follow the steps:

1. go to your dir
2. execute the command: "dir vendor/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions/src/Query/Mysql/Year.php" (Please check upper case and lower case as window is case insensitive )
3. Open file in your folder and check permission with right click on it

Comment: I edit my first message with a fot of the permission and The result to the command:     Répertoire:
    D:\Users\delph\Desktop\NetBeansProjects\ProjetMairie6\vendor\beberlei\DoctrineExtensions\src\Query\Mysql


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       10/10/2018     15:55            678 Year.php

Comment: Can you please check if a file is executable or not? Google that how to check file is executable or not in windows.The file should have permission 644.

Comment: I'm in Windows so it's ok

Comment: Problem solve. but I did not do anything more.

Comment: Strange, but i am happy that problem is solved

Answer (score 1):

in the query replace "Year" with "year"

so use the following code instead:

```
public function groupTypeInterArray(){
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('i')
            ->select('year(i.interventionDate)');
    return $qb->getQuery()->execute();
}
```

and you also need to change the corresponding line in the doctrine config :

replaces this code

```
Year: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Year
```

By this code

```
year: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Year
```

PS : to know which link you have to use to add a function correctly in doctrine config you have to go on [this link](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/config/mysql.yml)

Answer (score 0):

1.`dql:
            datetime_functions:
                year: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Year ???`

2.`dql:
            datetime_functions:
                Year: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Year ???`

Maybe
    `dql:
            datetime_functions:
                YEAR: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Year
                MONTH: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Month
                DAY: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Day`

Answer (score 0):

For me removing the vendor dir and do a fresh composer install solved the problem.